# How to call dynamic nested json object in retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, retrofit2

How to Call dynamic nested json object in android using retrofit.I have a JSON result in the following format, My question is: how do I access the content of "categories" since "food", "fashion", etc are all dynamic values? just give me an idea.

---

```
{
"offer": {
    "id": "JUN_HAIR_1302177631",
    "categories": {
        "electronics": {
            "address_1": "12 Mott St",
            "address_2": null,
            "city": "New York",
            "cross_streets": "Chatham Sq &amp; Worth St",
            "state": "NY",
            "zip": "10013"
        },
        "food": {
            "address_1": "12 Mott St",
            "address_2": null,
            "city": "New York",
            "cross_streets": "Chatham Sq &amp; Worth St",
            "state": "NY",
            "zip": "10013"
        },
        "fashion": {
            "address_1": "12 Mott St",
            "address_2": null,
            "city": "New York",
            "cross_streets": "Chatham Sq &amp; Worth St",
            "state": "NY",
            "zip": "10013"
        },
        .........
        .........

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: just give me an idea to start

Comment: ideally the categories should be a json array and the inner object needs to have something like category_name: xyz ..... This will make the model easy and more dynamic to model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HashMap`:

```
class Offer {
    private String id;
    private HashMap<String, Category> categories;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And the `Category` data class should look something like this:

```
class Category {
    @SerializedName("address_1")
    private String firstAddress;
    @SerializedName("address_2")
    private String secondAddress;
    private String city;
    @SerializedName("cross_streets")
    private String crossStreets;
    private String state;
    private String zip;

    // getters and setters;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Pojo to generate the class for your json.

Steps to follow

Go to package -> Create New -> Select Generate POJO from JSON

If the Option is not showing then you have not installed the plugin.

Go to Project Settings -> Plugins -> Install RoboPojoGenerator

This will generate the Java class for every Json Object. Ex below

```
public class Demo{

    @SerializedName("offer")
    @Expose
    private Offer offer;

    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("categories")
    private Categories categories;

    public void setOffer(Offer offer){
        this.offer = offer;
    }

    public Offer getOffer(){
        return offer;
    }

    public void setId(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setCategories(Categories categories){
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public Categories getCategories(){
        return categories;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return 
            "Offer{" + 
            "offer = '" + offer + '\'' + 
            ",id = '" + id + '\'' + 
            ",categories = '" + categories + '\'' + 
            "}";
        }
}
```

@SerializedName and @Expose annotation.

This will solve your problem.

Comment: i believe you should also give him the pojo for the Categories object

Answer (score 1):

Use Iterator to get all dynamic key of your categories object.

```
private void parseCategoriesJson(JSONObject data) {
// here data is your categories object.
    if (data != null) {
        Iterator<String> it = data.keys();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String key = it.next();
            try {
                JSONObject object=data.getJSONObject(key);
                // object is your electronics,food,fashion
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is list of models needed for that json, your models should be like this:

```
public class YourObject {
    @SerializedName("offer")
    private Offer offer;
}

public class Offer {
    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("categories")
    private Categories categories;
}

public class Categories {
    @SerializedName("electronics")
    private Electronics electronics;
    @SerializedName("food")
    private Food food;
    @SerializedName("fashion")
    private Fashion fashion;
}

public class Electronics {
    @SerializedName("address_1")
    private String address1;
    @SerializedName("address_2")
    private Object address2;
    @SerializedName("city")
    private String city;
    @SerializedName("cross_streets")
    private String crossStreets;
    @SerializedName("state")
    private String state;
    @SerializedName("zip")
    private String zip;
}

public class Fashion {
    @SerializedName("address_1")
    private String address1;
    @SerializedName("address_2")
    private Object address2;
    @SerializedName("city")
    private String city;
    @SerializedName("cross_streets")
    private String crossStreets;
    @SerializedName("state")
    private String state;
    @SerializedName("zip")
    private String zip;
}

public class Food {
    @SerializedName("address_1")
    private String address1;
    @SerializedName("address_2")
    private Object address2;
    @SerializedName("city")
    private String city;
    @SerializedName("cross_streets")
    private String crossStreets;
    @SerializedName("state")
    private String state;
    @SerializedName("zip")
    private String zip;
}
```

Comment: are they limited at least? if yes you should add all models for each object else you can use HashMap<String, JSONObject>